# Custom Model Binder for Complex composite objects HELP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I am trying to write a custom model binder but I'm having great difficulty trying to figure how to bind complex composite objects.

this is the class I'm trying to bind to:

```
public class Fund
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<FundAllocation> FundAllocations { get; set; }
}
```

and this is how my  attempt at writing the custom binder looks like:

```
public class FundModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, string modelName, Type modelType, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var fund = new Fund();

        fund.Id = int.Parse(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Id"]);
        fund.Name = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Name"];

        //i don't know how to bind to the list property :(
        fund.FundItems[0].Catalogue.Id = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["FundItem.Catalogue.Id"];
        return fund;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas

thanks
Tony

Comment: I just posted a question and then eventually figured out a solution to this same type of issue. For those interested, you may want to check out the below link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077481/how-do-i-pass-a-dictionary-as-a-parameter-to-an-actionresult-method-from-jquery-a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077481/how-do-i-pass-a-dictionary-as-a-parameter-to-an-actionresult-method-from-jquery-a)

Answer (score 8):

Do you really need to implement a custom ModelBinder here? The default binder may do what you need (as it can populate collections and complex objects):

Lets say your controller action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(Fund fund)
{
  //do some stuff
  return View();
}
```

And you html contains this:

```
<input type="text" name="fund.Id" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="fund.Name" value="SomeName" />

<input type="text" name="fund.FundAllocations.Index" value="0" />
<input type="text" name="fund.FundAllocations[0].SomeProperty" value="abc" />

<input type="text" name="fund.FundAllocations.Index" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="fund.FundAllocations[1].SomeProperty" value="xyz" />
```

The default model binder should initialise your fund object with 2 items in the FundAllocations List (I don't know what your FundAllocation class looks like, so I made up a single property "SomeProperty"). Just be sure to include those "fund.FundAllocations.Index" elements (which the default binder looks at for it's own use), that got me when I tried to get this working).

Comment: JonoW - do you have a link for good documentation for the standard model binder, or did you just look at the source?

Comment: Will, sorry don't have a link to any offical documentation, I was really just going on the advice of Phil Haack on his blog, as I had a similar problem - http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx. There may be a better way to do it in 1.0, not sure...

Comment: He is correct, you do not need a custom model binder. You can do this by manipulating the name field as demonstrated above.

Answer (score 3):

I have been spending too much on this exact same thing lately!

Without seeing your HTML form, I am guessing that it is just returning the results of selection from a multi select list or something? If so, your form is just returning a bunch of integers rather than returning your hydrated `FundAllocations` object. If you want to do that then, in your custom ModelBinder, you're going to need to do your own lookup and hydrate the object yourself.

Something like:

```
fund.FundAllocations = 
      repository.Where(f => 
      controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["FundItem.Catalogue.Id"].Contains(f.Id.ToString());
```

Of course, my LINQ is only for example and you obviously can retrieve the data anyway that you want. Incidentally, and I know that it doesn't answer your question but after much faffing around I have decided that for complex objects, I am best to use a ViewModel and have the default ModelBinder bind to that and then, if I need to, hydrate the model which represents my entity. There are a number of issues that I ran into which made this the best choice, I won't bore you with them now but am happy to extrapolate if you wish.

The latest [Herding Code podcast](http://herdingcode.com/?p=177) is a great discussion of this as are [K Scott Allen's Putting the M in MVC blog posts](http://odetocode.com).