# Where is the documentation for the standard ASP.NET MVC ModelBinder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I don't seem to be able to find any authoritative, up-to-date (i.e. for 1.0 final) documentation for the capabilities of the standard model-binder in ASP.NET MVC, particularly with respect to binding complex objects involving collections (and the naming requirements this places on the HTML form)

I have found a blog post from Phil Haack (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx), but it has a note at the top to say it's out of date and will be updated.   There was also a useful answer here: [Custom Model Binder for Complex composite objects HELP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714634) but I couldn't work out how he knew that stuff.

This page: http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/#MVC_ActionFilters is titled 'Action filters and Model Binders', but only actual contains information about filters.

Am I reduced to reading the source or buying the new 'Gang of Foreheads' book (and hoping it's better than the other Wrox books I've made the mistake of buying in the past)?  Or have I missed a good reference somewhere?

Comment: I have sent a request on the subject to Phil Haack. Hope he will answer something in his blog soon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For binding complex objects involving collections, check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711184/asp-net-mvc-example-of-editing-multiple-child-records/712817#712817) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711184/asp-net-mvc-example-of-editing-multiple-child-records).

Comment: Thanks for this - your link is a good answer, and so's the Hansleman post.  But what I was really hoping for is somewhere this is written down officially, rather than cobbling it together from assorted postings, each of which first needs to be assessed for 'up-to-dateness'.  But I appreciate the link, anyway.

Comment: I understand. I also have problems finding good general documentation about ASP.NET MVC. And I've come to conclusion that for now, the best thing to do is to have a test project and experimenting with how things work, alongside with reading the source code from time to time.